# mysql: delete & order by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-delete

want to delete duplicate posts using meta as duplcate metric, deleting recent duplicate posts and keeping the original version.

However it keeps the most recent duplicate version and deletes the older ones. So I tried adding an "order by" and it doesnt seem to work.

```sql
DELETE p, pm1
FROM 
    wp_posts p, 
    wp_postmeta pm1, 
    wp_postmeta pm2 
WHERE 
    (p.ID = pm1.post_id
    AND p.post_type = 'post'
    AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
    AND pm1.meta_key = 'syndication_permalink' 
    AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
    AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value)
ORDER BY p.ID ASC
```

help appreciated

Comment: There is no ORDER BY for a DELETE.

Comment: You are missing to show sample input and expected result of all involved tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use row_number() function

Here's a sample

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by ID ORDER BY name) AS Row
    FROM test
)

DELETE FROM cte
WHERE Row > 1
```